# Dictionaries in Xquery

Tags: dictionary, xquery

Are there any Dictionary formats in Xquery?

In python we can use `dict(zip())` to combine two lists, but in Xquery , do we have any such function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this isn't part of the standard, BaseX has a [map module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Map_Module) presently available.

Comment: The BaseX module actually is an implementation of Michael Kay's proposal @Dimitre Novatchev mentions.

Answer (score 3):

To combine two lists (sequences) in XQuery the syntax is:

```
let $combined-list := ($seq1, $seq2)
```

For example:

```
let $list1 := ('a', 'b', 'c')
let $list2 := ('d', 'e', 'f')
let $combined-list := ($list1, $list2)
```

You can also remove duplicates using:

```
distinct-values($list1, $list2)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Not that I am aware of**, but such a feature (called "maps") could appear in XSLT 3.0 or XPath 3:0.

See this post by Michael Kay: http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2012/01/#000188

Comment: The `dict(zip())` example could be written as [`map:new(fn:map-pairs(map:entry#2, $list1, $list2))`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-map-pairs) with this proposal.